# CKEditor in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, ckeditor

I wanna load CKEditor in CodeIgniter,I search a lot,but can't understand their way.

I placed ckeditor in **application/plugins** folder and now I wanna make editor ,so I do following in Controller Method.

```
include APPPATH.'plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.php';
$CKEditor = new CKEditor();
$CKEditor->basePath = '/'.APPPATH.'plugins/ckeditor/';
$initialValue = '<p>This is some <strong>sample text</strong>.</p>';
echo $CKEditor->editor("editor1", $initialValue);
```

but it makes simple teaxaria only ,with `This is some sample text.` value.
where is the problem and how should I solve it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I use this steps to add ckeditor to my codeigniter apps:

1) Download these files:

- This for Ckeditor: http://pastebin.com/fkK9e0RR
- This for Ckfinder: http://pastebin.com/SvyypmX4

2) Copy the files you just downloaded into your **Application/libraries** folder

3) Download the ckeditor helper here: http://pastebin.com/Cd3GqYbx

4) Copy the last file in **application/helper** folder as **ckeditor_helper.php**

5) Download the CKeditor controller here: http://pastebin.com/UD0bB9ig

6) Copy the controller in your **application/controllers** folder as **ckeditor.php**

7) Download the main ckeditor project from the official site: http://ckeditor.com/download/

8) Copy the ckeditor folder you just download into your asset folder (if you want you can also download the ckfinder project and put it in the same folder)

9) Add these line of js to your view file (adjust the path):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/asset/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/asset/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
```

10) In your controller add this php code and adjust the path:

```
$this->load->library('ckeditor');
$this->load->library('ckfinder');



$this->ckeditor->basePath = base_url().'asset/ckeditor/';
$this->ckeditor->config['toolbar'] = array(
                array( 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-','Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo','-','NumberedList','BulletedList' )
                                                    );
$this->ckeditor->config['language'] = 'it';
$this->ckeditor->config['width'] = '730px';
$this->ckeditor->config['height'] = '300px';            

//Add Ckfinder to Ckeditor
$this->ckfinder->SetupCKEditor($this->ckeditor,'../../asset/ckfinder/');
```

11) In your view print the editor with:

```
echo $this->ckeditor->editor("textarea name","default textarea value");
```

Comment: how to add image upload fucntionality? added Image in $config['toolbar'] but its not working. Please help

Comment: @user1149244 yes, you have to create it

Comment: @ Mansoorkhan Cherupuzha: I found this links helpful for me to make the image upload work in CKeditor http://derekmd.com/2013/03/ckeditor-image-upload-in-codeigniter/.  You might want to give it a try. One of the best tutorial I've found so far.

Comment: Works perfect using the listed steps!

Comment: I have follow your step, But I am facing issue that whenever I am click on Browse Server button that popup screen show me blank. Could you help me for that?

Comment: I have ask question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798373/browse-server-is-not-working-in-ckeditor-with-ckfinder

Comment: Everything works fine, except the CKEditor does not obey the height parameter. Why?

Comment: All your links are deleted ... :(

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi None of them works .... all are dead

see this http://pastebin.com/fkK9e0RR

Comment: Man, if I click on the link I see the code...All the links are set to EXPIRES: NEVER

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi : 
Can You Help , how can I get value of ckeditor field in Controller . while it is having 
'echo $this->ckeditor->editor("textarea name","default textarea value");'
to show ck editor , how can i submit value using this?
any idea ?

Comment: @DevangMistry you need to wrap it in a form and use the submit event to retrieve content in Controller

Comment: links not working. would you please correct the links?

Comment: is this method secure to insert in database?

Comment: @metalbox this will no insert any data into your database, it just show the steps to add CKEditor to textareas, the form submission is on your own

Answer (score 4):

You could otherwise do this:

1. copy the CKEditor files to a folder in your source's root eg ckeditor
2. Include the CKEditor files in your view file

   ```
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url(); ?>style/format.css">
   ```
3. finally your textarea in your html document

   ```
    <textarea cols="80" id="edi" name="editor1" rows="10">
                   <?php echo $page_content->message1; ?>
                               </textarea>
                               <script>

                                   CKEDITOR.replace('edi');

                        </script>    </body>
   ```

This works great for me.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I found a sweetly simple 2-code-line explanation here:  http://www.iprogrammerindia.in/how-to-integrate-ckeditor-in-codeigniter/#comment-73

Just in case the link disappears I will paste the text here.  This worked for me 8/1/14:

Include this line in your view where you want to use ckeditor and place your ckeditor folder in root folder.  Here i placed in js/ckeditor/ in root folder

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Next include the below line in the same view,

```
<?php echo form_textarea(array('name' =>'desc','id'=>'desc','class'=>"ckeditor")); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Download CKEditor package from https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/
2. Unzip folder in your Codeigniter project folder at your preferred location.
3. Include the `<script>` element loading CKEditor in your page.
4. Use the `CKEDITOR.replace()` method to replace the existing `<textarea>` element with CKEditor.

See the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
        <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
        <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, more easy impossible

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know this question is old, but this is what I did, and seems to be easiest for me.

1. In my root, I have a directory called 'js' and within that I have a
   directory called 'plugins'. I copied the ckeditor files there.
2. Then in `application/views/common/headers` directory I have a header file
   titled '`ckeditor.php`'. Within this file just lies the following code:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="php echo base_url();?>
> js/plugin/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
> ```

3. Then in the controller, I added the header file to the $data object to pass to the view:
   `$data['header_files']  =   array('header1','header2','header3', 'ckeditor'); // header file names were changed for the sake of my client`
4. Then, you pass the $data object of to the view of course:
   `$this->load->view('common/admin-template',$data);`
5. then I just called CKEDITOR.replace('textareaNameHere');

and voila. it works

Answer (score 0):

same problem is i am fessing but just little thing u need all file in asset folder in the root folder.
my controller part is

```
$this->load->library('ckeditor');
    $this->load->library('ckfinder');

    $this->ckeditor->basePath = base_url().'assets/admin/ckeditor/';
    $this->ckeditor->config['toolbar'] = array(
                                                array( 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-','Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo','-','NumberedList','BulletedList' )
                                                );
    $this->ckeditor->config['language'] = 'en';
    $this->ckeditor->config['width'] = '730px';
    $this->ckeditor->config['height'] = '300px';            

//Add Ckfinder to Ckeditor
    $this->ckfinder->SetupCKEditor($this->ckeditor,base_url().'asset/admin/ckfinder/');
```

---

---

my view part is

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Description</label> <?php echo form_error('event_description'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->ckeditor->editor("event_description",((isset($event_description)) ? $event_description : ''));?>      
</div>
```

i putting ck editer folder in asset folder and asset folder in root file
like
C:\wamp\www\site\assets\admin\ckeditor

Comment: Is this an answer, or a new question?

Comment: it is answer of above question

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to use Ckeditor is through CDN, Use this in your view file and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CKEditor</title>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/18.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea name="editor" id="editor" rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="Insert text here" class="form-control"></textarea>
<script>
ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
.then( editor => {
console.log( editor );
} )
.catch( error => {
console.error( error );
} );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

for more information and styling of ckeditor and use of different styles of ckeditor you can visit the https://cdn.ckeditor.com/#ckeditor5

**If you are looking for Document editor of Ckeditor then follow the below link**
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/quick-start.html#document-editor

use the example and you will be able to insert the document editor in your view file